Postfix configuration to block spammer domain isn't working
I have an Ubuntu 22.04 cloud VM with Postfix 3.6.4-1ubuntu1.3 installed that I largely use for receiving e-mails sent to addresses at my personal domain that I provide when signing up for less-important website accounts.  In the past few months, one of these addresses has been receiving too many unsolicited e-mails from the same domain that are managing to get through the server's basic spam defenses.  I would like to block these e-mails at the Postfix level, and I thought I set things up properly, but the e-mails are still coming through.
The "From" addresses for the spam e-mails all share the same domain — here stupidspammers.example — and they are all sent (per both the "Received:" headers and the mail logs) from a subdomain of spamgateway.nil.
I tried to block the e-mails as follows:

I created /etc/postfix/access with the following contents:
stupidspammers.example REJECT


I ran sudo postmap hash:/etc/postfix/access

I added the line smtpd_sender_restrictions = check_sender_access hash:/etc/postfix/access to /etc/postfix/main.cf

I restarted Postfix with sudo systemctl restart postfix


When this setup proved insufficient, I changed the contents of /etc/postfix/access to spamgateway.nil REJECT and repeated steps 2 & 4, but the e-mails are still coming through, and I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

It turns out that smtpd_sender_restrictions = check_sender_access ... is only for matching the "MAIL FROM" address — and, for the specific spam I'm getting, this address happens to use a third domain name different from the others for some reason.  In order to match against the DNS name of the connecting server instead, I had to set the contents of access to spamgateway.nil REJECT and change the smtpd_sender_restrictions line in main.cf to:
smtpd_client_restrictions = check_client_access hash:/etc/postfix/access

